# Private repository passing through kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

We have tried to setup hivemq manifest file. We have hivemq docker image in our private repository

Step1: I have logged into the private repository like

```
 docker login "private repo name"
```

It was success

After that I have tried to create manifest file for that like below

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hivemq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: hivemq1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        xxxxx some envronment values I have passed
        name: hivemq
        image: privatereponame:portnumber/directoryname/hivemq:
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883

Its successfully creating, but I am getting the below issues. Could you please help any one to solve this issue.

hivemq-4236597916-mkxr4                    0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          1h

Logs:

Error from server (BadRequest): container "hivemq16" in pod "hivemq16-1341290525-qtkhb" is waiting to start: InvalidImageName

Some times I am getting that kind of issues

Error from server (BadRequest): container "hivemq" in pod "hivemq-4236597916-mkxr4" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a private docker registry with Kubernetes it's not enough to `docker login`.
You need to add a Kubernetes `docker-registry` Secret with your credentials as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/. Also in that article is `imagePullSecrets` setting you have to add to your yaml deployment file, referencing that secret.

Comment: Thank you for response. Even I have followed above procedure.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/, followed this link. Till "base64 -d secret64" every thing was correct. I got my credentials details as well. After that I have tried to pull the image using same yaml file which is mentioned in the link.

Comment: containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: 
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: myregistrykey

In the image place I have tried in these many ways

<registryname>:protname/directoryname/hivemq:<dockerversion>
hivemq:<docker version>
directoryname/hivemq:<docke version>
portname/directoryname/hivemq:<dockerversion>

Comment: I have tried these many ways even though I am facing the issues

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this on my machine, kubectl v1.9.0 failed to create the secret properly. Upgrading to v1.9.1, deleting the secret, recreating it resolved the issue for me. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57427